# Why the console command of Vampire Lord doesnt work in Skyrim Dawnguard DLC?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim, skyrim-dawnguard

I want to increase my perk of Vampire Lord skill in Skyrim Dawnguard DlC. I used console command but it doesn't work. I used Power of the Grave, a Vampire Lord ability, or a console command `player.addperk.02005998` but it didn't work.

How can I make this work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't use console commands this often, but I think that you should
write the command without the "." between "addperk" and "02005998". It should look like this:

```
player.addperk 02005998
```